# Disable single option in list-fancy-select

Tags: custom-field, form

When using a custom select list field i can disable single options in it by setting an attribute.
Here a simple version:

```
<field name="somefield" type="mylist" label="COM_YOLO_MYFIELD" />
```

mylist.php

```
...

// $elements = get data from DB

foreach ($elements as $el) {
    $attribs = [];
    if ($el['mute'] == 1)
        $attribs = array('option.attr' => 'optionattr', 'attr' => array('disabled' => 'disabled', 'class' => 'muted'));
    }
    $options[] = HTMLHelper::_('select.option', $el['id'], $el['title'], $attribs);
}

return array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $options);
```

That works. I get a select list with custom disabled options.

When adding `layout="joomla.form.field.list-fancy-select"` to the field xml the disabled options no longer work.

Is it possible to disable single options in the list-fancy-select layout?